# Is it possible to print more than last line with Get (<<) without using Print commands?

Tags: scripting, output

I want to run my *Mathematica* scripts from the terminal and I want it to print lines like MATLAB would.  That is, suppress output by ending a line with `;`, and otherwise print the output of the line.  `Get` (`<<`) only prints the last line.

Without using Print[var] and saving variables after every line... Is this possible?

Comment: Your scripts ought to have `Print[]` lines somewhere in the file, then...

Comment: "...without using `Print[var]`..." - why?

Comment: I think adding // Print after every line is the best I can do, saves me from having to Print specific variables...

Comment: without using Print[var] because I don't want to have to put in specific variables, I want a general solution...

Comment: In that case, I suppose postfix application of `Print[]` is what you want, indeed.

Comment: Now, if I could filter the script with a regular expression, before evaluating the script and after `Get`, I could change all occurences of `;` to `//Print`.  Is this possible?

Comment: Possible or not, it sounds like an insane idea. Think of what would happen for this line: `a = 1; b = 2;`

Comment: True that.  Well, would have to assume one semicolon per line.  Anyway, I can do it externally with sed or vim.

Comment: If the only semicolon in your line is that of `CompoundExpression` and that too, only 1 per line, you can set `$PreRead := If[FreeQ[#, ";"], #, # /. ";" -> "// Print"] &`. This should work in the front end, but I haven't tested it with the terminal

Answer (score 3):

You print by having a `Print[]` on the expression you want to print.  End all other statements with `;`.

```
fooToPrint = bar[...]; Print[fooToPrint];  
fooNoPrint = bar[...];
```

e.g.,

```
a = 1 + 2;
Print[a];

b = 3 + 4;

a = b;
Print[a];
```